# Is there a GCC __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ equivelent for literal arguments it was fed?

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, strace

If my function is:

```
void foo(bool bar)
{
    qDebug() << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
}
```

`foo(getBool());` will output `"void foo(bool bar)"`

I would like to have more of a strace result, so that:

`foo(getBool());` will output `"getBool()"`

What is the best way to go about this?

A requirement is that `foo(boolbar)` will be placed into a dynamic library, as such:

```
#include "Custom Library/output_tools.h"
```

into projects.

Comment: Make `foo` a preprocessor macro and use the stringize macro operator? What is the use-case? What is the actual problem you want to solve?

Comment: What happens when you have `foo(getBool()); foo(someOtherMethod());`? Similarly, if you have *calls* to `foo` in another translation unit, with `extern void foo(bool bar);` or similar, how does the information about the call site reach the definition of `foo`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Will that work for external libraries? This intended for an outputting library I use across projects which is used to beautify my console application outputs. The problem I want to solve is that I want to streamline `printBoolFunctionAndResult("getBool()", getBool());` to `printBoolFunctionAndResult(getBool());`

Comment: Of course, macros can be defined in header files. (remember that it's a macro, not a real function)

Comment: In a library, dynamic or static, there is no way of knowing how a function was called and what the original calling expression might have been. All you know, if `foo` is a function (and not a function-like macro defined in a header file) is that you receive an argument that is a `bool` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use a macro for this?

```
#define printBoolFunctionAndResult(bar) qDebug() << #bar << " " << bar;
```

This uses the stringize operator to convert the macro arguments to a string, and first prints the argument directly, and then evaluates it.

Here is a working example with `std::cout`: https://repl.it/repls/IntelligentGrayGermanpinscher

Comment: Will this work for an external dynamic library? I should have specified that as a requirement.

Comment: I will give it a shot. Get back to you in 5 minutes

Comment: Looks pretty good, but one small snag in the `#define` in regards to deduplication; how do I use functions from the header I placed `#define` in? For example, `#define printBoolFunctionAndResult(bar) qDebug() << blue(#bar) << red(bar);` – using that requires me to define blue and red locally, or turn blue and red into static functions so I can call them without an object.

Comment: Hmmm I suppose I could turn blue and red into defines as well...?

Comment: @Akiva You only need to *declare* the functions. Their definitions can be in any translation unit or library.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am trying to parse your comment. I need to declare blue() and red(). Do I declare them in the in the header outside the class, in the header inside the class, or inside my code?